# For the Noobs: Starting Bitcoin games. I cannot transfer Bitcoins, or use Faucets

Tags: earnings, gaming

I started with Bitcoin a few days ago, and have mainly been going to free faucets and sites like that to get free Bitcoins. I just recently found out about Bitcoin games like the one at https://satoshimines.com/. I played around with it and like it, but I tried to transfer some Bitcoins to my account on that website.

It would not let me, and gave this reason...

```
There are not enough funds in this wallet to send 0.00001634 BTC  ($0.01) .
Note that you can only spend confirmed transactions.
Remember that the sender pays a fee.
```

I have `0.00008 bitcoins` as of right now.

---

My BitChain - https://blockchain.info/address/148AadbRDjYeLSn4ZTe73bButUngMKz4cW

---

Also, when I start playing the game linked above, it states not to share the link. Why?

Answer (score 2):

> Remember that the sender pays a fee.

That seems to be your problem. According to [this info](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees), if your transaction output is smaller than `0.01 BTC`, you need to pay a minimum `0.0001 BTC` transaction fee. Since you only have `0.00008 BTC`, there are not enough funds to make the transaction (note also that the minimum fee is over 6x the amount you're trying to transfer, so it might not be a good idea to do so).

As for your other question, your game seems to be uniquely identified by that URL, so sharing the link would allow someone else to continue the game for you (and lose **your** money). I'm not really sure how the mechanism behind this works, though...